# When Indexing a string, s[i] works yet s.at(i) throws. Why?

Tags: c++

Ran across this curious situation where replacing [] with at() failed.
We have a vector of strings some of which have embedded nuls separating subsequent use tags.
The code extracts the initial string up to the first nul in each vector.
Is use of [] undefined behavior that at() is catching?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std::literals;
using std::string, std::vector, std::cout;

int main()
{
    // given a vector of strings with embedded nuls, extract chars until the first nul
    vector<string> vs{"item1\0A"s, "item2"s};
    // This works fine.
    for (const string& s : vs)
    {
        for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++)
            cout << s[i];
        cout << "\n";
    }
    // s.at(i) is a bounds checking version of s[i]
    // but fails
    for (const string& s : vs)
    {
        for (int i = 0; s.at(i); i++)   // Out of Range Exception thrown here
            cout << s.at(i);
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Th difference is that `s[i]` returns a reference to a "nul character" (a `char` with value of `'\0'`) if `i == s.size()` whereas `s.at(i)` throws an exception.   Outputting a nul character usually produces no visible effect on screen.  Either way, you've be better off looping using iterators that represent the range of characters to be output, rather than testing characters in the string  e.g.  `for (std::string::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i) cout << *i; ` and variants or (since C++11) a range-based loop like  `for (char c : s) cout << c;`.

Comment: @Peter The code doesn't output nul chars. It just uses the presence of a nul, whether embedded in the string or  at the end to terminate processing that string. It's kind of a corner case. Note that accessing an iterator at end() is UB unlike `s[s.length()]` so you can't use an iterator to test nul.

Comment: My point is that the loop, if written using iterators (including via a range-based for) does not need to test for nul at all.

Comment: @Peter of course it needs to test for nul as that is required to terminate processing the string when embedded nuls exist. `[]` is special here because only a test for nul is needed. Range based approaches require a second test for end of range.  And iterators also require a second test since accessing the nul with an iterator at the end of a string is UB.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no undefined behavior
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at
For operator [], if pos == size(), a reference to the character with value CharT() (the null character) is returned.
However, at(size()), will throw. Something to keep in mind.

```
// This works.
for (const string& s : vs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() && s.at(i); i++)
        cout << s.at(i);
    cout << "\n";
}
```